# Docker Compose Build is not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run my Node.js app in Docker. I use docker-compose to build different services. For me, basic `sudo docker-compose --verbose build` is not working.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:

  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./atatus-dev/:/usr/src/app
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:0.10
```

After running this command `docker-compose --verbose build`, I can see following in the console.

**Console Logs**

```
compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.yml
docker.auth.auth.load_config: File doesn't exist
compose.cli.command.get_client: docker-compose version 1.8.0, build f3628c7
docker-py version: 1.9.0
CPython version: 2.7.9
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker base_url: http+docker://localunixsocket
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker version: KernelVersion=4.2.0-42-generic, Os=linux, BuildTime=2016-08-18T05:22:43.932726241+00:00, ApiVersion=1.24, Version=1.12.1, GitCommit=23cf638, Arch=amd64, GoVersion=go1.6.3
compose.service.build: Building web
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker build <- (pull=False, stream=True, nocache=False, tag=u'vagrant_web', buildargs=None, rm=True, forcerm=False, path='/home/vagrant', dockerfile=None)
```

After this prints, nothing happens. The build process stays there continuously.

I use following versions.

```
docker-compose version 1.8.0, build f3628c7
Docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638
```

Could you please tell what is wrong with this configurations?

Comment: What is this command really doing? CMD [ "npm", "start", "#custom" ] Can you show the content of your package.json?

Comment: Sorry. I removed it. I just placed it for testing purpose.

Comment: @DavidLevel It is not even pulling the node image from docker. I mean, first  line of the docker file itself is not executing. I removed all other contents from my Dockerfile. As of now, my Dockerfile has only one line `FROM node:0.10`

Comment: @DavidLevel You can see the logs that I pasted. It is not ending or throwing  any errors. It stays there indefinitely.

Comment: Did you notice this line? docker.auth.auth.load_config: File doesn't exist

Comment: What does it mean? How do I fix it? I could find any answer through google search.

Comment: It seems to be an install issue. Take a look to this thread https://github.com/blockchain-certificates/cert-viewer/issues/53

Comment: Side-note, are you _sure_ you want to use Node.js **0.10** ? Current is now **12.10**

Answer (score 12):

I have just had an issue that looked quite similar to yours with `docker-compose build` today, and in my case the problem (being stuck without any error or anything happening on the command line) was due to the large build context sent to docker (apparently it is completely silent about that). Once I have added proper entries in a `.dockerignore` file (to effectively filter out big subdirectories present in my workspace), the problem went away.

Comment: +1. I was waiting for one of my builds for a long time and suddenly docker started to display logs. If you have a large build then you need to be patient for a while with docker.

Answer (score 3):

i had this issue and adding `.dockerignore`  didnt work, then using
`docker compose up --build`  solved it.